# Getting around the 500 row limit

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have written a Google Fusion Tables script I'm happy with (below), but it's loading only 500 rows of points in my table, which has over 20,000 rows. This is my first time in this neighborhood and I was really surprised to find the limit. Is there some way to load all the rows?

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
        <title>Points in box</title>

        <link href="./stylesheets/example.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
        <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/no_javascript.html"></noscript>

            <!-- Find box coordinates javascript -->
            <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlon.js"></script>

            <!-- Type label text javascript -->     
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/label.js"></script>

            <!-- Visulization javascript -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

            <!-- Initialize visualization -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
              google.load('visualization', '1', {});
            </script>

      </head>
      <body class="developers examples examples_downloads examples_downloads_points-in-box examples_downloads_points-in-box_index">

            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var store_table = 4121905;

        //send a call to GViz to retrieve lat/long coordinates of the stores
        function getStoreData() {
          //set the query using the input from the user

            var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT Latitude,Longitude,Impressions FROM " + store_table);
          var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

          //set the callback function
          query.send(doLoop);

        }

        function drawBox(topleftx, toplefty, bottomrightx, bottomrighty) {

          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng( topleftx, toplefty ),
            new google.maps.LatLng( bottomrightx, bottomrighty )
          );

        var overlay = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          map: carto_map,
          bounds: bounds,
          strokeColor: "#0000ff",
          strokeOpacity: 0.20,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "#0000ff",
          fillOpacity: 0.050,
        });
        }

        function doLoop(response) {
            numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();

        //Basic
           var cartodbMapOptions = {
             zoom: 7,
                     center: new google.maps.LatLng( 37.926868, -121.68457 ),
             // center: new google.maps.LatLng( 40.7248057566452, -74.003 ),
             // disableDefaultUI: true,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           }

            // Init the map
            carto_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),cartodbMapOptions);

            for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

                var centerX = response.getDataTable().getValue(i,0);
                var centerY = response.getDataTable().getValue(i,1);
                var imps = response.getDataTable().getValue(i,2);

                var centerPoint = new LatLon(centerX,centerY);
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(centerX,centerY);

                var toplefty = centerPoint.destinationPoint(-45, 6)._lon;
                var topleftx = centerPoint.destinationPoint(-45, 7.7)._lat;

                var bottomrighty = centerPoint.destinationPoint(135, 6)._lon;       
                var bottomrightx = centerPoint.destinationPoint(135, 7.7)._lat;     

                drawBox(topleftx, toplefty, bottomrightx, bottomrighty);     

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latLng,
           draggable: false,
                 markertext: imps,
                 flat: true,
           map: carto_map
         });

           var label = new Label({
             map: carto_map,
                 position: latLng,
                 draggable: true
           });
           label.bindTo('text', marker, 'markertext');
             marker.setMap(null);

            }

        }

        $(function() {
                        getStoreData();
             });

          </script>

                <div id="map"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There are table size limits to Google Fusion tables. Welcome to the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by using the json call method. Code below.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>David's Build Up</title>

            <link href="./stylesheets/example.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
            <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/no_javascript.html"></noscript>

                <!-- Find box coordinates javascript -->
                <script
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
            </script>

                <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlon.js"></script>

                <!-- Type label text javascript -->     
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/label.js"></script>

                <!-- Visulization javascript -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

                <!-- Initialize visualization -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  google.load('visualization', '1', {});
                </script>


            <script type="text/javascript">

                    function drawBox(topleftx, toplefty, bottomrightx, bottomrighty) {

                      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                        new google.maps.LatLng( topleftx, toplefty ),
                        new google.maps.LatLng( bottomrightx, bottomrighty )
                      );

                    var overlay = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                      map: carto_map,
                      bounds: bounds,
                      strokeColor: "#0000ff",
                      strokeOpacity: 0.20,
                      strokeWeight: 2,
                      fillColor: "#0000ff",
                      fillOpacity: 0.050,
                    });
                    }

              function initialize() {

                        // Set the map parameters
                        var cartodbMapOptions = {
                            zoom: 5 ,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng( 40.313043, -97.822266 ),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        }
                    // Initialize the map
                    carto_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),cartodbMapOptions);

                        // Query to grab the data
                var query = "SELECT Latitude, Longitude, Impressions FROM " +
                    '[encrypted table ID here]';
                var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);

                // Construct the URL to grab the data
                var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query'];
                url.push('?sql=' + encodedQuery);
                url.push('&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ');
                url.push('&callback=?');

                        // Set the number of rows
                        var numRows = 3500;

                // Get the variables from the table, in a loop
                $.ajax({
                  url: url.join(''),
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  success: function (data) {
                    var rows = data['rows'];
                    var ftData = document.getElementById('ft-data');
                    for (var i in rows) {
                      var centerX = rows[i][0];
                      var centerY = rows[i][1];
                                    var imps = rows[i][2];
                                    // Set the center points
                                    var centerPoint = new LatLon(centerX,centerY);
                                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(centerX,centerY);
                                    // Set top left points
                                    var toplefty = centerPoint.destinationPoint(-45, 6)._lon;
                                    var topleftx = centerPoint.destinationPoint(-45, 7.7)._lat;
                                    // Set bottom right points
                                    var bottomrighty = centerPoint.destinationPoint(135, 6)._lon;       
                                    var bottomrightx = centerPoint.destinationPoint(135, 7.7)._lat;
                                    // Draw the box
                                    drawBox(topleftx, toplefty, bottomrightx, bottomrighty);
                                    // Drop markers
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                               position: latLng,
                               draggable: false,
                                     markertext: imps,
                                     flat: true,
                               map: carto_map
                              });
                               var label = new Label({
                                 map: carto_map,
                                     position: latLng,
                                     draggable: true
                               });
                               label.bindTo('text', marker, 'markertext');
                                 marker.setMap(null);
                    };
                  }
                    });

              }
            </script>
          </head>

          <body onload="initialize()">
                <div id="map"></div>
                <div id="ft-data"></div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Just the clue I was hoping for. Was able to make this work for my test case.  The ChartTools API handles a lot of convenience translating FT response object to a DataTable, but applies a 500 row limit.  Using Ajax directly allows one to get around that limit, but also the burden/benefit of working directly with the lower-level data structure it returns.

Answer (score 1):

The Gviz API does have a 500 row limit for a given query.

Any table is limited to 100,000 *mappable* rows, but that's well outside your reported 20,000 rows.

The new Javascript API, currently accepting Trusted Testers, offers JSON format support for any number of rows returned for a query.  You can apply for the TT program by requesting membership in this group: 
https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-api-trusted-testers

-Rebecca

Answer (score 0):

The fusiontables/gvizdata URL is intended for Gviz charts and so is limited to 500 points. There are other ways to query that don't have that limitation. See https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I routinely refresh a 2500 row table by deleting all rows and inserting new ones. The loop in my code that constructs the INSERT sql has a nested loop that just counts to 400, sends that sql, and then starts building another one with the next 400 records.