# google visualization query limit

Tags: google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google visualization query for which data is coming from fusion table as,

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=select * from *******************");
```

But it select only first 500 rows of data. How to overcome this limitation?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859323/getting-around-the-500-row-limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fusion Tables SQL queries are deprecated.  The new version of the API is not limited to 500 rows, see the [Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) for details.

Edit:

Here is an example Dashboard using the Google Fusion Tables code Odi posted in comments below:

```
function drawTable(response) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Country Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Population in 1960');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Population in 2000');

    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
        rows.push([response.rows[i][0], parseInt(response.rows[i][1]), parseInt(response.rows[i][2])]); 
    }
    data.addRows(rows);

    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        containerId: 'table_div',
        chartType: 'Table',
        options: {

        }
    });

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        containerId: 'control_div',
        controlType: 'StringFilter',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0
        }
    });

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.querySelector('#dashboard'));
    dashboard.bind([control], [table]);
    dashboard.draw(data);
}

function getData() {
    // Builds a Fusion Tables SQL query and hands the result to  dataHandler
    var queryUrlHead = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=';
    var queryUrlTail = '&key=AIzaSyCAI2GoGWfLBvgygLKQp5suUk3RCG7r_ME';
    var tableId = '17jbXdqXSInoNOOm4ZwMKEII0sT_9ukkqt_zuPwU';

    // write your SQL as normal, then encode it
    var query = "SELECT 'Country Name', '1960' as 'Population in 1960', '2000' as 'Population in 2000' FROM " + tableId + " ORDER BY 'Country Name' LIMIT 10";
    var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);

    var jqxhr = $.get(queryurl, drawTable, "jsonp");
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['controls'], callback: getData});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6BXsy/

Give the date format `yyy-mm-dd`, this is how you would create Date objects from it:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
// other columns

var rows = [], dateArray, year, month, day;
for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
    dateArray = response.rows[i][0].split('-');
    year = parseInt(dateArray[0]);
    month = parseInt(dateArray[1]) - 1;
    day = parseInt(dateArray[2]);
    rows.push([new Date(year, month, day) /*, other data */]); 
}
data.addRows(rows);
```

Comment: To clarify, the old SQL API is deprecated but the visualization API is still used for charting. But we do strongly recommend using the new API for general querying.

Comment: @Rod any chance you could send some of your visualization-related staff to check up on the `[google-visualization]` tag from time-to-time? While asgallant here is worth his weight in gold, having the support of the people actually working on the project would be a great benefit (it may also give some hints in to how people are using the API, what features people struggle with/don't exist, and bring happiness to us folks looking for guidance)

Comment: @asgallant - Any such sample for reference?

Comment: @PradeepShankar, sorry, I don't have one.  I've never used Fusion Tables for anything.

Comment: @PradeepShankar here is an example usage of the Fusion Tables API with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/Sbt2P/ All you need is your API key and a query to run.

Comment: @Odi - Is it possible to mix up the your query with google dashboard control wrapper? ie, taking data to control wrapper using your above example.

Comment: @PradeepShankar, yes you can use that with a Dashboard and controls.  Once the data is in a DataTable, the Visualization API doesn't care where you got it from.

Comment: @PradeepShankar, I added example code for a Dashboard based on Odi's jsfiddle to my answer.

Comment: @PradeepShankar, javascript Date objects are constructed in the form `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)`.  Months are 0-indexed, so January is 0, February is 1, March is 2, etc.  You can leave off any elements at the end that you don't want to include and javascript will use 0 in their place.

Comment: Is the following format correct? `data.addColumn('date', 'my date');`

Comment: @PradeepShankar, yes that is the correct format for adding a date column to the DataTable.

Comment: @asgallant - Then `response.rows[i][0]` will parse that column?

Comment: Assuming that the dates are in column 1 of the response, then that is the column you want to pull the dates from, but I doubt that the dates in the response will be javascript Date objects; most likely, they will be strings, which you will have to parse into Date objects, according to the format I posted in a comment above.

Comment: How to include the above date parsing in the code `var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
        rows.push([response.rows[i][0], parseInt(response.rows[i][1]), parseInt(response.rows[i][2])]); 
    }` Assume if I have a date column in my FT and I want to parse the months?

Comment: It depends on what FusionTables formats dates like.  Insert the line `console.dir(response.rows[0][0]);`, open the page in Chrome or Firefox, and look in the developer's console to see what is output.  Likely, it is a string that you will have to split into year, month, and day.

Comment: Assume it is as `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: is this not possible to format like `var monthformatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: "MMMM"}); monthformatter.format(data, 0);` after parsing the data?

Comment: I edited my answer with code to parse the dates.  And yes, you can use the formatted on the Date column like that.